# Large file (5 GB) hashing with bcrypt takes long time (246sec, ~4 minutes)

Tags: java, performance, hash, out-of-memory, slowdown

I have a very simple code, which is designed to avoid OutOfMemory exceptions. To this reason, the file is streamed and chunks are created, each chunk is hashed, and the final hash is generated from these (this called a Hash tree: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_list).

My questions are the following:

- Hashing with [bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) takes very long time (246sec for a 5GB file), I'm not sure it is a real problem (or is it normal?), but I consider the time very-very long. (will it freeze the program?)
- Also, is it possible to speed it up? I planning to parallelize hashing each list elements, it is a good approach? Should I do it?

The code sample is using a 5GB test file downloaded from: https://testfiledownload.com/

My code is the following:

```
package main;

import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.util.StopWatch;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        // Sample test file downloaded from: https://testfiledownload.com/
        StopWatch sw = new StopWatch();
        sw.start();
        String h_text = encryptor(iparser("C:\\Users\\Thend\\Desktop\\test_5gb\\5gb.test"));
        sw.stop();
        System.out.println(" Hash: "+h_text+" | Execution time: "+String.format("%.5f", sw.getTotalTimeMillis() / 1000.0f)+"sec");

    }


    public static List<byte[]> iparser (String file) throws IOException {

        List<byte[]> temp = new ArrayList<>();
        if (Files.size(Path.of(file)) > 104857600) { // 100 MB = 104857600 Bytes (in binary)

                // Add chunk by chunk
            try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file)) {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[10485760]; //  10 MB chunk
                int len;
                while ((len = fis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    temp.add(buffer);
                }
                return temp;
            }

        } else {

            // Add whole
            try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file)) {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[(int) file.length()]; //  Add whole
                int len;
                while ((len = fis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    temp.add(buffer);
                }
                return temp;
            }
        }
    }

    public static String encryptor(List<byte[]> list) {

        BCryptPasswordEncoder bcpe = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<>();

        if (list.size() > 1) {

            // If there is more than one element in the list
            list.forEach((n) -> {
                //String tohash = new String(n, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                String tohash = new String(n);
                String hashedByteArray = bcpe.encode(tohash);
                temp.add((hashedByteArray.split(Pattern.quote("$"))[3]).substring(22));

            });
            return bcpe.encode(String.join("", temp));

        } else {

            // If there is only one element in the list
            return bcpe.encode(String.join("", temp));

        }
    }
}
```

The console output:

```
Hash: $2a$10$60BSOrudT4BT3RC4dqcooupGd6fmg0/LU0RLGhBTSLvbZgypGuyBq | Execution time: 246,88400sec

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Bcrypt is not appropriate for hashing large files, it's not meant for that. Why are you using Bcrypt?

Comment: Bcrypt is designed for password hashing. It is intentionally very, very slow, in order to slow down cracking attempts. It's not suitable for file hashing, especially not 5GB worth.

Comment: Why do you use bcrypt? It is purposely built to be slow. Sha2 would probably be a better choice.

Comment: First sentence [at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt): *bcrypt is a password-hashing function*

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk , JohnKugelman , BasilBourque Dear all, I completely aware of that, this is an experimental project. I would like to simply try to speed it up as much as possible. (I dont want to decrease iterations of the algorithm or anything) I want to implement in a program similar to Quickhash)

Comment: What is the purpose of your experiment? I don't see the sense in trying to make bcrypt work fast on large files. That's not what it's used for. It would make more sense if you wanted bcrypt to run faster when feeding it passwords, or if you fed your large files to a different hashing algorithm like SHA-2 or SHA-3.